# Change false to true in `$scope.$broadcast('test', false);` in the `<div ng-show = "test.data">` view

Tags: angularjs

When I change in controller `false` to `true` or `true` to `false`

`$scope.$broadcast('test', false);`

in the controller view, there are no changes:

`<div ng-show = "test.data">`

I do not know why. You have an idea.

the example is similar here:
https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

```
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular
     .module('app')
     .controller('aController', aController);

 function aController($scope) {

     initialize();

     function initialize() {
              set();
     }
     function set() {

        return Service.test()               
            .then(function (data) {

                switch (data.status) {
                    case 'SUCCESS':
                        if ( data.value === false ){  
                            $scope.$broadcast('test', false);
                        } else {
                            $scope.$broadcast('test', true);                            
                        }
                       break;

                    default:
                        $scope.$broadcast('test', true);                         
                        break;
                }

             })
             .catch(function (error) {

             });
     }
    $scope.$on('test', function ($event, data) {

    });


  }

 })();
```

Comment: Are you expecting `$scope.$broadcast('test', false);` to automatically set your `$scope.test.data` value to be `false`?

Comment: yes, for example: `if (value === true ){ $scope.$broadcast('test', true); } else { $scope.$broadcast('test', false); }`

Comment: Let's see your controller code. `$scope.$broadcast()` just broadcasts a message/event. You have to handle that message/event in your controller. There's no automatic setting of properties that occurs when you use `$scope.$broadcast()`.

Comment: how to handle this change `$scope.$broadcast('test', false);` in the controller?

Comment: Can you please add your controller code to your question? Is `$scope.test` an object in your controller or simply a primitive?

Comment: I was editing a post

Comment: I don't see a `test` variable anywhere in your controller. Nor do I see a `$scope.$on()` to handle the broadcast. Why are you even using `$scope.$broadcast()`? Also, do you need the `return` in your `function set()`?

Comment: in the set() method, set the values for $scope.$broadcast()? I want them to change automatically. does not set in the `ng-show = "test.data"` view

Comment: I added a method  `$scope.$on('test', function ($event, data) {
    });` at the end of the `set()` function, but it did not help

Comment: The scope/rootScope event bus and its methods `$emit`, `$broadcast`, and `$on` are all  deprecated. Using it will make migrating your app to Angular 2+ more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
<div ng-show="test.data">
    ...
</div>
```

in your view then what you should do in your controller is:

```
function aController($scope) {
    initialize();
    function initialize() {
        $scope.test = { data: true };
        set();
    }

    function set() {
        Service.test()               
            .then(function (data) {
                if(data.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                    $scope.test.data = data.value;
                } else {
                    $scope.test.data = true;
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) { });
    }
}
```

There's no need to even use `$scope.$broadcast()`.